# Xgboost Parameter Tuning

Tags: xgboost

Are there methods to tune and train an `xgboost` model in an optimized time - when I tune paramaters and train the model it takes around 12 hours to execute?

I would like to run the solution 100 times with 100 seeds; my machine has 8 GB RAM and I can't buy a cloud solution.

Answer (score 3):

Typically XGBoost does not require many parameters to be tuned to get good performances.

I would start with optimizing the **n_estimators, max_depth and min_child_weight** parameters only. This should already bring you close enough.

Another thing you can do to speed-up the process is to prefer **Random Search** over Grid Search, since in most cases is as or more effective.

You could also have a look at the [LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) implementation, which is **faster** (and needs **less memory**) than XGBoost.

Comment: Another option is using a "smart" search algorithm - in packages like `BayesianOptimazation`, `hyperopt`, or `skopt`.

Comment: I would advise against tuning n_estimators and would use the early stopping method instead. Also, if your data is of high dimension tuning stuff like colsample_bytree/level/node can be useful.

Comment: @aranglol what do you mean exactly by "high dimension"? Many features/inputs? Or does high dimension include rows as well? Would it also include a combo of how many categories a feature has? e.g. shoes_column=high-tops, cross-trainers, walking-shoes.

Comment: @Edison I wrote this a while ago, but dimension always refers to the number of columns, not rows. In general, having a lot of rows is never bad from a pure statistical perspective. High dimension can also refer to the number of distinct categories as well, which is often referred to as the cardinality of a variable. Note that if you do one hot encoding for example (which is the standard way to deal with categorical variables like your shoe example), this implies that a categorical variable with a large # of categories will add a large number of columns, i.e. make your dimension "higher".

Comment: @aranglol Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use less folds in cross validation, for example cv=2 or cv=3 in GridSearch to save time and memory.

I usually optimize a few parameters like: learning_rate, max_depth, min_child_weight and reg_alpha.

And since you mentioned you can't buy cloud solution, there is a free cloud called Google Colab https://colab.research.google.com/ which offers free RAM (I think up to 25 GB) and GPU. You can upload your ipython notebook and dataset or link it to your Google Drive. I use it for parameters tuning because it's faster than my low RAM computer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of running hyperparameter optimisation is through Bayesian optimization. A package like `skopt` is already built to implement that in the context of `xgboost` and other `scikit-learn` predictors.

Check the documentation here: https://scikit-optimize.github.io/#skopt.BayesSearchCV